# Multi Tenancy App : Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs

Tags: angularjs, facebook, redirect, oauth

It is not a duplicate question. I have tried all the methods suggested and nothing really works.

I have configured an FB  application and added

(i)An app domain, `http://sample.io`

(ii)Site URL :  `http://sample.io/`

Also under Facebook Login,

Valid Oauth redirect URIs:

```
http://sample.io/
```

**Note: It was working before previously for sub domains also.**
In application we support multi tenancy so the site url will go as,

```
http://johndoe.sample.io/
http://obama.sample.io/
```

**Issue:** Login Button does not apepar until we add these app domains in the App Domains Field also in Valid Oauth redirect URIs

**Question:**
Is there a way to fix this? or an API to add subdomains through code?

Comment: The way to fix it is to add all the redirect URIs. And no, there is no API for that.

Comment: @CBroe it was working for all the urls before 3 months

Comment: And now things have changed. Facebook now demands that this field is set.

Comment: @CBroe can this be done on a server side?

Comment: _"And no, there is no API for that"_